update-initramfs takes hours to generate initrd file
Whenever there is a kernel update, the installing happens extremely slowly, because the mkinitramfs step in update-initramfs proceeds at only a few kB per minute:
$ echo "Current size:"; ls -s /boot/initrd.img*.new; sleep 60; echo "Size 1 minute later:"; ls -s /boot/initrd.img*.new
Current size:
28377 /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-42-lowlatency.new
Size 1 minute later:
28705 /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-42-lowlatency.new

Notably, if I let this process continue, it will eventually finish, after over 12 hours. However, waiting for 12 hours for a kernel update is ridiculous, and something is obviously wrong. Can anyone help me figure out why kernel updates are so slow on my PC? In case it matters /boot is on a separate ZFS pool named bpool. This pool has plenty of space:
$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
bpool           2.6G  344M  2.3G  14% /boot
$ zpool list bpool
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool  4.50G  2.15G  2.35G        -         -      -    47%  1.00x    ONLINE  -

OS info:

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

